# Hide only on certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a script that checks for any  tag that also has a SRC="self". My function should function like this:

1. Check if `img src="self"`
2. If true, hide the parent div
3. If false, do nothing

Currently the function actually hides every `img` regardless of `src`. If I replace the jQuery `hide()` action then the function works perfectly. It just seems like it isn't quite performing the hide function like I anticipated.

```
function changeSourceAll() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (images[i].src.indexOf('self') !== -1) {
            $(".redditThumbnail").hide();
        }
        else (){}
    }
}
changeSourceAll();
```

Sample HTML is below. I have multiple `.listrow` div elements identical to this and the function removes all the `.redditThumbnail` divs.

```
<div class="listrow news">
    <div class="newscontainer">
        <div class="redditThumbnail"></div>
        <div class="articleheader news">
            <div class="actionmenu">
                <p class="mediumtext floatleft alignleft">
                    author
                </p>
                <div id="redditUsername"></div>
                <div class="floatright">
                    <div class="redditPermalink material-icons"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="redditTitle mediatitle news"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [attribute-equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find all of the `<img>` elements that point to "self" and then hide their parents :

```
// Hide the closest thumbnail for elements that match this constraint
$('img[src="self"]').closest('.redditThumbnail');
```

**Example**

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(){
      $('img[src="self"]').closest('.redditThumbnail').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='redditThumbnail'>
  A (has self)
  <img src='self' />
</div>
<div class='redditThumbnail'>
  B (doesn't have self)
  <img src='self-test' />
</div>
<div class='redditThumbnail'>
  C (has self)
  <img src='self' />
</div>
<hr />
<button>Hide Self-Referencing Images</button>
```

Comment: You are an MVP. Also, thanks to you and the comments below explaining my foolishness. I can't believe I didn't catch that. When my script ran into 1 instance of a SELF src tagged image it was removing ALL redditThumbnails, just like you all suggested. It makes much more sense now that I see it written out.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with hiding every `img` is because you select and hide all `.redditThumbnail` elements for every matching item. To fix this you could use this:

```
$(images[i]).closest('.redditThumbnail').hide();
```

However a better approach entirely would be to use `filter()` and find only the `.redditThumbnail` elements which match the requirements. Try this:

```
$('.redditThumbnail').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('img[src="self"]').length != 0;
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding all: `$(".redditThumbnail").hide();`. I guess you should do something like `$(images[i]).hide();`